# Nodes.js Rest API

Tags: node.js, api, server

I'm learning how to code Rest API with node.js, but I'm wondering what is the next step to send a REST API on a real server (once it's working with localhost)? It's not easy to find how to proceed on the web... Any suggestions?

Comment: You're creating a REST API or calling a REST API?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

#### Self Hosting

1. Host it on your own machine.

You can use a service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) or [PageKite](https://pagekite.net/). They are super simple to try and are free to experiment.

They will generate an URL for you, than you can access your server through that .

You can also do it the hard way.

1. On your router settings you need to forward the port you are using to your machine.
2. Also on your router settings, you need to make your internal IP static.
3. Create a firewall exception for that port.

With that done, you can reach your server through your public IP address.

#### Cloud Hosting

1. VPS (Cheaper, but not as scalable)

You can rent a Virtual Private Server, which is a virtual machine running the OS of your preference (Linux is more common). Then you can just upload your code and start your server. Some even offer free domains for you to reach the server.

There are many hosting platforms. Check [this](https://www.websitebuilderexpert.com/web-hosting/vps/).

2. Cloud hosting Platforms (More expensive, infinitely scalable)

Platforms like [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com) or [DigitalOcean](https://digitalocean.com) offer virtual machines that are infinitely scalable.

AWS offers the [ec2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2) service and DigitalOcean offers the [Droplets](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/droplets) service.

There are LOTS of resources online on how to do it.

[aws ec2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html)

[aws ec2](https://sumantmishra.medium.com/how-to-deploy-node-js-app-on-aws-with-github-db99758294f1)

[DigitalOcean](https://www.learnwithjason.dev/blog/deploy-nodejs-ssl-digitalocean)

[DigitalOcean](https://medium.com/@haxzie/deploying-node-js-application-to-digitalocean-setting-up-the-server-99e1d65fa291)

[VPS](https://www.scalahosting.com/blog/installing-node-js-on-a-vps-server-2/)

[VPS](https://medium.com/@ipenywis/deploying-nodejs-application-to-server-full-guide-74d89f1cab9f)

Paste this in Google `how to deploy nodejs vps OR digitalocean OR aws OR ec2`

And be happy